# jqGrid Search functionality on non-default anchor

Tags: events, search, jqgrid, window, modal-dialog

I have a button named [Filter] that I'm trying to call the grid search modal on click. I have yet been able to find the call that the search button uses inline.

It uses `<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-search"></span>` classes for the search icon/button.

So something like

```
$('.filter').live('click', function (event) {
        $('ui-icon-search').trigger('click');
});
```

Edit, found it.

`$('.filter-grid').live('click', function (event) {
        $("#search_products").click();
});`

Was calling the parent div id on click and not the span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

`$('.filter-grid').live('click', function (event) { $("#search_products").click(); });`

Was calling the parent div id on click and not the span.